# How to type special characters like @, £, $ with Norwegian keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

As some of you may already know, in order to type in special characters (like @, £, $, et cetera), you need to hold Ctrl and Alt. However, I tried several options in the Keyboard Layout and progressed nowhere. Holding Ctrl and Alt while pressing 2 so I can type @ does not work.

Comment: Which keyboard layout setting are you using and what's the physical layout of your keyboard? -- As far as I'm aware Ctrl+Alt+<key> is a shortcut supported only by a select few systems. Alt-Gr is the usual special-chars-key.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I never really used Alt Gr for anything before, it was very usual to press Ctrl + Alt. Alt Gr works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: No need to be sorry. It obviously is working-as-intended: No need for you to memorize a different combination with Windows.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> is only used when the keyboard layout doesn't include an <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd> key, as such it is supported by Windows for emulation purposes (as in: keeping the functionality across multiple layouts).

Using the <kbd>Alt-Gr</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> combination is standard and should be supported by your keyboard layout.

(In extension to my comment)